# qt creator android Build Fail build.xml:283: null returned: 1

Tags: android, qt, build, sdk, qt-creator

I'm trying to build an android app using qt creator but I have a problem. It usually works just fine but now it give me this error:

> [dx] Error occurred during initialization of VM 
>    [dx] Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

and

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:888: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:890: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 1
>   Total time: 4 seconds
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
>   Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
>   Building the android package failed!
>   -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
>   17:30:23: Le processus 
> "D:\Qt5.8.0_android\5.8\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" s'est terminé avec le code 14.
>   Erreur lors de la compilation/déploiement du projet untitled13 (kit : Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have apache ant problem.

you should set [SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit), [NDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDK), [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit), [apache ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) to your Qt Creator.

More information :[Getting Started with Qt for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html)

download apache ant from [here](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

[image: Screenshot]

For start build and run Qt Android examples to make sure all of those are working fine on your device.

Comment: i did all those things , i even redownloaded what you gave me and used it , i said yesterday it was working just fine here

Comment: @Abibad Abdou, ok what's difference since yesterday ? i don't have your code. try Qt Android examples, to make sure problem is not your code.

Comment: i did try qt android examples , same problem

Comment: my code works again , like if it needed to sleep lol , i don't understand how but it works again and i didn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

Use Gradle instead of Ant.
Actualy ant is deprecated.