# Error building Qt Application for Android target with Qt Creator 4.3.1 / Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, qt, build

Is there workaround on how to build app for android target with Qt earlier than 5.9 having latest Android Studio (2.3.3) and latest Qt Creator (4.3.1) on Windows? 
I'm getting following error message while building dummy "HelloWorld" example:

```
   The installed SDK tools version (25.3.0) does not include Gradle scripts. The minimum Qt version required for Gradle build to work is 5.9.0
```

Comment: maybe this page help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256919/qt-creator-android-build-fail-build-xml283-null-returned-1/45257065#45257065

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not the case. Ant is installed but "Use Gradle instead of Ant" checkbox is grayed out and always checked. It says "(Ant builds are deprecated)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like workaround is to downgrage SDK tools to the version 25.2.5. Can be downloaded from [here](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.ru/p/android-sdk-tools.html).

For my environment I kept both versions of SDK tools, switching between them with symlink:

```
     tools -> /c/devtools/Android/SDK/tools.25.2.5
     tools.25.2.5
     tools.26.0.2
```