# Error building Qt app for Android with Qt Creator

Tags: android, c++, qt

When I tried to build QtFireExample with my QtCreator, failed with below error message.

> The installed SDK tools version (26.1.1) does not include Gradle
>   scripts. The minimum Qt version required for Gradle build to work is
>   5.9.0/5.6.3 Error while building/deploying project QtFirebaseExample (kit: Android) When executing step "Build Android APK"

My android studio is 3.2.1.  And SDK tools 26.1 is also installed.
qt version is also above 5.9.0
What I did mistake?

```
❯ qmake --version
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.0 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.0/lib
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. There was this thread but it didn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692558/error-building-qt-application-for-android-target-with-qt-creator-4-3-1-android

Comment: It should download that the first time you try to build an android binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more steps to follow before you can deploy your first Android app using QtCreator. Installing SDK tools is not enough. Here is what I did, I'm using Windows, but hopefully the steps are the same under Ubuntu.

- Install QtCreator using the link provided by Hitokage, include QtCreator (I got version 4.8.0), and Qt 5.12.0 binaries for your platform + needed Android (armv7, x86...)
- Get JDK 1.8.X.X
- Get NDK r18b (or a more recent version)
- Get SDK tools 26.1.1 (what you already did)
- SDK tools itself is not enough, some SDK modules must be installed, from SDK tools folder, run:

  - `sdkmanager platform-tools`
  - `sdkmanager build-tools;28.0.3`
  - `sdkmanager extras;google;usb_driver`
  - `sdkmanager platforms;android-22` (which is enough for me, you may want something different based on your target Android devices)

Then open QtCreator, Go to "Mobile devices" (my french version calls it "Appareils mobiles"), then make it point to installed JDK, SDK, NDK, clic Apply and then kits should be automtically created. Now you are ready to compile and deploy and Android app for API 22.

Note that gradle is automatically downloaded by QtCreator first time you'll request a deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried downgrading the SDK Tools which didn't work. What worked for me however was downloading the [official QT installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer) (working on Linux), installed QT to a new directory along with ARM64-v8a and ARMv7 (which probably solved the problem, I didn't have that in the package I installed from Arch repo). Now I can (after allowing the developer and debug mode on the device) deploy the app on the phone.

EDIT: Then chose one of those auto-detected kits.