# Qt with android 5.9.0 installation erorr

Tags: android, qt, qt-installer, qtandroidextras, qt5.9

I am trying to install Qt with android , but i am facing issues while adding AVD,

sdk location : D:\android-sdk
ndk location : D:\android\android-ndk-r15c-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r15c
creator showing it found 10 tool chains for this ndk 
ant location : D:\Apache-ant-1.9.6\src\script\ant.bat

whenever i try to start avd manager i am getting a pop message like as below

AVD manager tool is not available in the installed SDK tools(version 26.0.2). use the command line tool "avdmanager" for advanced AVD management.

and if i try to bulid sample project i am getting error like as below

Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Android for x86 (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.0 for Android x86))
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

if anyone knows what's wrong, kindly help me to solve this problem.
i am using Qt 5.9.0 with Qt creator 4.3.1
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257065/5068056  check the screenshot and sdk location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  
i did all those things exactly. but still I'm not able to add new avd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem here is that Google removed/moved a bunch of tools from Version 26 of the android SDK! This happend after the release of Qt 5.9.0, and thus the SDK 26 cannot be used with Qt 5.9.0

You can now either use the SDK Version 25, or update your Qt to 5.9.1. This should at least fix the build problems.

If you decide to update Qt, this will however still not solve the AVD problem. As of SDK 26, the AVD graphical tool is no longer part of the SDK, only a command line tool (as stated by the message you see). The graphical variant is available in Android Studio only. (Don't ask why, just google being google...)

You can still use that command line tool though. Go to `<android-sdk-location>/tools/bin` and type `avdmanager --help` to see how to use the tool to create virtual devices.

---

**EDIT:** With the recent QtCreator, a graphical SDK and AVD manager have been embedded into QtCreator itself, providing a useful alternative to the old ones.

Comment: Thank you felix. 
i used SDK  25.2.5 with Qt5.9.0 it worked.